# Why custom compiled Python 3.5 app crashes when waiting for Web Socket message, but apt-get installed Python 3.4 does not

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm running into an exception within an application running on a self-compiled Python 3.5.2 that I cannot explain. [There's a web socket handler on the server side](https://github.com/home-assistant/home-assistant/blob/dev/homeassistant/components/websocket_api.py) that does nothing else than taking incoming connections and then waiting for input on the web socket itself:

```
request = ...
wsock = aiohttp.web.WebSocketResponse()
yield from wsock.prepare(request)
msg = yield from wsock.receive_json()  # throws TypeError
```

The exception that is being thrown:

`TypeError('Received message 258:AttributeError("\'_UnixSelectorEventLoop\' object has no attribute \'create_future\'",) is not WSMsgType.TEXT',)`

In each call of the stack trace I didn't find any line throwing this error. When running the same code with a pre-built Python 3.4, the web socket server works just fine. We use the Python 3.5.2 that comes pre-configured with OpenEmbedded since we are building our own Linux.

```
(Pdb) w
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/bin/hass(11)<module>()
-> sys.exit(main())
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/__main__.py(396)main()
-> exit_code = setup_and_run_hass(config_dir, args)
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/__main__.py(325)setup_and_run_hass()
-> return hass.start()
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/core.py(144)start()
-> self.loop.run_forever()
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asyncio/base_events.py(276)run_forever()
-> self._run_once()
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asyncio/base_events.py(1172)_run_once()
-> handle._run()
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asyncio/events.py(120)_run()
-> self._callback(*self._args)
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asyncio/tasks.py(292)_wakeup()
-> self._step(value, None)
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asyncio/tasks.py(236)_step()
-> result = coro.send(value)
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py(417)start()
-> resp = yield from self._request_handler(request)
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py(289)_handle()
-> resp = yield from handler(request)
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asyncio/coroutines.py(143)coro()
-> res = yield from res
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asyncio/coroutines.py(143)coro()
-> res = yield from res
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/components/http/ban.py(58)ban_middleware_handler()
-> return (yield from handler(request))
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/components/http/__init__.py(425)handle()
-> result = yield from result
  /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asyncio/coroutines.py(143)coro()
-> res = yield from res
> /srv/homeassistant/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/components/websocket_api.py(322)handle()
```

So I'm supposing that there's something wrong with our self-compiled Python 3.5.2. What could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web socket server application is using the latest `asyncio` version 3.4.3 that was installed via `pip`. That library however seems to conflict with the usage of Python 3.5.2. Python 3.5.2 should come with its own asyncio that has evolved over the version available on pypi. This said, providing the proper asyncio library along with Python 3.5.2 has fixed the issue.